# Use matchedGeometryEffect to create 'slide' effect for border

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-matchedgeometryeffect

I'm trying to create a custom 'tab' selection control with a horizontal row of options and the user can select one of N number of options. The 'selected' option will have a 'border' around it. Here's a prototype I made:

```swift
@objc public enum ContactTabStyle: Int, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three, four
    
    public var segmentTitle: String {
        switch self {
            case .one: return "Hello"
            case .two: return "World"
            case .three: return "Three"
            case .four: return "Four"
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    let segments: [ContactTabStyle] = [.one, .two, .three, .four]
    @State var selectedTab: ContactTabStyle = .one
    
    @Namespace var tabName
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(segments, id: \.self) { segment in
                Button {
                    selectedTab = segment
                } label: {
                    Text(segment.segmentTitle)
                        .padding(12.0)
                        .border(selectedTab == segment ? Color.blue : Color.clear, width: 3.0)
                        .cornerRadius(4.0)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: segment.segmentTitle, in: tabName) // doesn't work
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The view looks and works fine, but I can't get the animation to 'slide' from one selection to another. It just does a normal SwiftUI fade-in-and-out. I believe I should use `matchedGeometryEffect` to get the sliding effect, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried adding the `matchedGeometryEffect` to the label around the button as well, but it didn't work either.

Here's a preview of what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Text`s don't need to match geometry - it's the *borders* that need to match geometry.

If you use `border` to make a border, the border is not its own "view", so you can't modify *only* the border with `matchedGeometryEffect`. One workaround is to add the border as the `background` of either the `Text` or the `Button` (these produce slightly different effects - see which you like better).

```
Button {
    selectedTab = segment
} label: {
    Text(segment.segmentTitle)
        .padding(12.0)
        .background {
            if selectedTab == segment {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                    // every border should have the same id!
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "selection", in: tabName)
            }
        }
        
}
```

or

```
Button {
    selectedTab = segment
} label: {
    Text(segment.segmentTitle)
        .padding(12.0)
        
}
.background {
    if selectedTab == segment {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
            .stroke(Color.accentColor, style: .init(lineWidth: 3))
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "selection", in: tabName)
    }
}
.animation(.default, value: selectedTab)
```